# Conditional Modal Display Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am building a web application using Laravel 5.2. I am stuck at a scenario and need help on how to resolve it.

I have my routes defined like this

```
Route::get('/deals-coupons/{merchant_url_text}', ['uses' => 'DealsController@index']);

Route::get('/out/{deal_id}', ['uses' =>'ClicksController@index']);
```

On my DealsController, I am returning a view (called mlp view) with a few buttons. Each button has a url like

```
http://localhost/out/{deal_id}
```

Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is this.

User clicks on a button and that is to the out route. On my out route, I am doing some server side tracking in my ClicksController. Once done, I am doing this

```
return redirect('deals-coupons/'.$merchant_url_text);
```

So basically, I am redirecting user to an out route to do server side tracking and now I am redirecting them back to my original mlp view.

How do I make sure that I show a modal at this point. The current modal I have in my mlp view shows up every time I hit the route

```
Route::get('/deals-coupons/{merchant_url_text}', ['uses' => 'DealsController@index']);
```

Is there a way to check if the view was loaded after the out route so I can only display the modal then and not every time?

Also, is this the right approach or can I code this whole scenario in a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should use sessions for that - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session